# Ruby on rails: dynamic code not working into erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my code

```
   Here i want to include youtube video id dynamically. Its not taken here Kindly give me a solution

 <%= link_to image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= video.provider_uid %>/hqdefault.jpg"), "http://www.facebook.com" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need string interpolation here, not ERB tag:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{video.provider_uid}/hqdefault.jpg"), "http://www.facebook.com" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite the code like that:

```
<%= link_to "http://www.example.com" do %>
  <%= image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{video.provider_uid}/hqdefault.jpg") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
<%= link_to image_tag("http://img.youtube.com/vi/#{video.provider_uid}/hqdefault.jpg"), "http://www.example.com" %>
```

this is the code